# Java Script Server side web api calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest

So I'm working on my first website using angularjs for the front end and nodejs for the server side (I'm probably saying that wrong). I'm trying to find out, is it bad practice to make web api calls from the server.js? If so why? If not, what is a good way of going about this?

My code looks like this.

```
 //UserController.js snippet
 $scope.sendMessage = function (sendemailto,badgeNum  ) {
        var reqdata = {
            "recipiant": sendemailto
            , "badgeNumber": badgeNum
        }
        $http.post('/api/RequestVerify', reqdata).then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.debug("RequestVerify pass: ");
            console.debug(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.debug("RequestVerify FAIL: ");
            console.debug(response);
        })
    }

//server.js snippet
app.post('/api/RequestVerify', function (req, res) {
   ... do database stuff ...
   //DoaPostToAnotherWebApi(); 
   res.send(data);
}
```

I could see this being bad practice due to the fact api calls could be strung together unintentionally and make for slow sites. However, I didn't find any forums posts on this topic.

Thanks

Comment: depends on what you need, if your front end can fetch the data from the desired web service directly, do it!


But if you want to save these responses and store them persistent for your front end, your server should make the requests.

Comment: Where are you making the http requests to on the server? Within the same server or some external site?

Comment: The "DoaPostToAnotherWebApi();" is just going to be a post the the Microsoft graph api to send out an email in this situation.